# Do any studies show what the effect is of skipping daily language practice for one day?

Tags: reference-request, study-habits, frequency

Most language teachers that you talk to strongly recommend daily practice.  Some applications, like Duolingo, add incentives to encourage users to practice every day.

Is there actually evidence that daily practice makes that much of a difference?  Has anyone attempted to quantify **how much vocabulary** is lost by periodically skipping a day of language practice?

Comment: In general I'd put more weight on having steady habits for practicing established.  Daily habits are easy to keep and easy to keep track of.

Comment: I don't think this is possible to answer, as the effect of skipping one day of practice depends entirely on the method and intensity of study.

Comment: I personally don't have any problems not studying a language for a day.

Comment: A similar question which user fi12 asked about a month later: [Does learning a language consistently every day help you learn it faster?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/627/does-learning-a-language-consistently-every-day-help-you-learn-it-faster)